# Binding style for user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, user-controls

This is my xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <Style.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=CueBannerText}" Foreground="LightGray" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to bind set the Label Content by code if I call the control in my project. The way I do it is like this:

```
Public Class UserControl1 
Public Property CueBannerText As String
    Get
        Return _oText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _oText = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _oText As String = "Search"

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.DataContext = Me
End Sub
End Class
```

If I call my control in the code With this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:Noru="clr-namespace:NoruTextBox;assembly=NoruTextBox">
<Grid>
    <Noru:UserControl1></Noru:UserControl1>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

my control won't show 'Search' as the TextBox isn't selected or contains anything.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you'll either need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your `UserControl` code behind, or declare a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Public Shared CueBannerTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("CueBannerText", GetType(String), GetType(TestView), 
    New PropertyMetadata("Search"))

Public Property CueBannerText() As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(CueBannerTextProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set
        SetValue(CueBannerTextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

> Disclaimer: I just converted this to VB using an online converter, so I can't confirm its correctness.

Using a `DependencyProperty` will also enable you to set this value in a `Style`, `Animation` (unlikely in this situation), or a `Binding`:

```
<Noru:UserControl1 CueBannerText="{Binding SomeValue}" />
```

Comment: I tried this out, but no success again :/ My xaml code for the user control is this: http://pastebin.com/A8fxAhSQ, it vb code is this: http://pastebin.com/bhpAe55U. I try to implement the control in my other application by adding it DLL to the resources and this is the code: http://pastebin.com/6xR40RZL